Extension of tangent vector field on sphere
I'm trying to solve the following from Elon Lages Lima's Book on homotopy and covering spaces.
Exercise 3.11. Let $f,g \colon B^2 \longrightarrow S^2$ be continuous maps, such that $(x,y)\in S^1 \Rightarrow f(x,y)=(x,y,0), g(x,y)=(-y,x,0)$. Prove that there exists $(x,y)\in B^2$ with $f(x,y)=\pm g(x,y)$.
Note: $B^2$ is the closed disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
My thoughts so far:

One can take the cross product between the given vector fields $f \times g \colon B^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. We just know how it behaves when restricted to $S^1$:
$$(f\times g)|_{S_1}(x,y)=(0,0,x^2+y^2)=(0,0,1). $$
This means that on the equator of the sphere, the vectors given by the cross product are tangent to the sphere. If we could assure that the vector field $f\times g$ is tangent to the sphere  for any $(x,y)\in B^2$, then we could apply the hairy ball theorem and guarantee the existence of some $v=(x',y')$ such that $(f\times g)(v)=(0,0,0)$ and then the vectors $f(v)$ and $g(v)$ are parallel and satisfy the condition required.


I have another approach to the problem, but this may require tools that have not been introduced yet.
If there are no points $(x,y)$ for which $f(x,y) = \pm g(x,y)$, then $\{f(x,y), g(x,y)\}$ forms a linearly independent set at every point $(x,y) \in B^2$.  Consequently, the given functions combine to give a map $$(f,g): B^2 \to V_2(\mathbb{R}^3),$$ where $V_2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is the space of $2$-frames in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Alternatively, if you're not familiar with $V_2(\mathbb{R}^3)$, since $V_2(\mathbb{R}^3) \simeq SO(3)$ we can also write down the map as $$(x,y) \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} | & | & | \\ f(x,y) & \tilde{g}(x,y) & (f \times \tilde{g})(x,y) \\ | & | & | \end{pmatrix},$$ where $\tilde{g} = g - \left\langle f, g \right\rangle f$.
Returning to the problem, we are given the function restricted to the circle: $(f, g)|_{S^1}: S^1 \to V_2(\mathbb{R}^3)$.  In matrix form, this is $$(x,y) \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} x & -y & 0 \\ y & x & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Asking for this function to extend to the disk $B^2$ is equivalent to asking for $(f,g)|_{S^1}$ to be nullhomotopic.
Note that $(f,g)|_{S^1}$ is simply the inclusion of $S^1 \cong SO(2) \hookrightarrow SO(3)$ as the upper-right block.  Here are some facts about the fundamental group of $SO(3)$:

$\pi_1 SO(3) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$.  One quick way to see this is that it is double-covered by $SU(2)$, or equivalently $SO(3) \cong \mathbb{R}P^3$ which is double-covered by $S^3$.
The inclusion $SO(2) \to SO(3)$ sends a generator in $\pi_1 SO(2) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ to a generator of $\pi_1 SO(3)$. To see this, use the long exact sequence in homotopy associated to the fibre bundle $SO(2) \to SO(3) \to S^2$.

Assuming these facts, we see that $(f,g)|_{S^1}$ is not nullhomotopic, and hence cannot be extended to the disk.  Therefore, there must be a point $(x,y)$ for which $f(x,y) = \pm g(x,y)$, by contradiction.

You are right, you used machinery that I don't now yet. However, I could follow the idea until your second bullet point where you mention the long exact sequence in homotopy associated to the fibre bundle. Thanks a lot for your time!
